# symfony2 - Doctrine - How to do a multiple select with a count and group by

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony2 and Doctrine I would like to execute a query that returns a count and a group by.

Here's what I've tried.  This is the SQL I want to run:

```
SELECT   `terrain_id` , COUNT( * ) 
FROM     `Partie` 
WHERE     1 =1
GROUP BY `terrain_id`
```

**With my entity:**

```
class Partie
{   
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gp\UserBundle\Entity\User", 
        inversedBy="parties",         cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gp\JeuxBundle\Entity\Terrain")
     */
    private $terrain;
```

**This is my PartieRepository**

```
public function getTest(\Gp\UserBundle\Entity\User $user){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('count(p), p.terrain')
    ->where('p.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->groupBy('r.terrain')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 19 near 'terrain FROM': Error: 
Invalid PathExpression.   Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably want to go with a [Native Query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

```
$sql = "SELECT terrain_id as terrain,
                count(*) AS count "
            ."FROM Partie "
            ."GROUP BY terrain_id;";


$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addScalarResult('terrain', 'terrain');
$rsm->addScalarResult('count', 'count');
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
return $query->getResult();
```

Just add in any having / where clauses as needed.

The following is my result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [terrain] => 
            [count] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [terrain] => 1
            [count] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [terrain] => 2
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

The lack of `terrain` in the first array is due to null `terrain_id`.

**EDIT**

OP has unexpected results, so here are some troubleshooting steps:

1) Try a `var_dump($query->getSQL());` right **before** the `return` statement, and run the SQL directly against your DB. If this produces incorrect results, examine the query and alter the `$sql` as appropriate.

2) If #1 produces correct results, try a `var_dump($query->getResult());` right **before** the return statement. If this produces correct results, something is going on deeper in your code. It's time to look at why `terrain` is being filtered. It may be as simple as removing or changing the alias in SQL and `addScalarResult`.

3) Try an even simpler function:

```
    $sql = "SELECT distinct(terrain_id) FROM Partie;";

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addScalarResult('terrain_id', 'terrain_id');
    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    var_dump($query->getSQL());
    var_dump($query->getResult());
    return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I only get the 'count' with this method even if the query looks good. Any idea why ?

Comment: @adrien_om I'm not sure. My test code works on my end. Please update your original post with your new code and results.

Comment: do you have this king of relation too ?
`**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gp\JeuxBundle\Entity\Terrain")
     */
    private $terrain;`

Comment: @adrien_om Are your results shown from a var_dump right before `return $query>getResult()`?

Comment: My `terrain` property is not `private`, it's `protected`. But I tried both, and that doesn't seem to make a difference, at least not in a Native Query.

Comment: My results are shown from a var_dump of the `return` of my function.
I didn't mean to talk about `private` or `protected` but about `ManyToOne`

Comment: Tried chat, but you don't have enough rep yet. Let's try this one step at a time. I will edit my post with the steps.

Comment: Yes, I edited my post. I finally get what I wanted thanks to your posts. I'm now trying to get the entity instead of the id. Hope I'll be luckier :)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs on this line : `select('count(p), p.terrain')` where you are trying to use `p` alias that doesn't exist anymore. The `select` method override the default alias of the `createQueryBuilder()`. To avoid this, use `addSelect` instead or specify clearly the `from` method.
Try this :

```
public function getTest(\Gp\UserBundle\Entity\User $user){
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
->addSelect('count(p), p.terrain')
->where('p.user = :user')
->setParameter('user', $user)
->groupBy('r.terrain')
->getQuery()
->getResult();

}
```

or this :

```
public function getTest(\Gp\UserBundle\Entity\User $user){
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
->select('count(p), p.terrain')
->from('YourBundle:YourEntity', 'p')
->where('p.user = :user')
->setParameter('user', $user)
->groupBy('r.terrain')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
}
```

Comment: If I add the **addSelect** I get the same error as above and if I add the **from** I get the following error : `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 94 near 'p WHERE user': Error: 'p' is already defined.` as it's defined in : `$this->createQueryBuilder('p')`

So I tried to used `$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery()` instead of `$this->createQueryBuilder('p')` but I get the following error

`Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::select()`

Answer (score 0):

### How to execute a raw Query with count and group by:

Hook onto your manager and make a new connection:

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$conn = $manager->getConnection();
```

Create your query and fetchAll:

```
$result= $conn->query(
'select count(p.id) foobar, p.myid from foobartable p group by p.myid'
)->fetchAll();
```

Get the data out of result like this:

```
$this->appendStringToFile("first row foobar is: " . $result[0]['foobar']);
```