# How to write this query with join and count in DQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am querying a table called `Goal` (`match_id`, `player_id`, `team_id`) which returns a list total amount of goals scored per player.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as scored
FROM goal
INNER JOIN matches
ON goal.match_id = matches.id
WHERE matches.league_id = 19
GROUP BY player_id;
```

The query above gives me correct information but I am having trouble converting this to DQL.

My attempt:

```
public function findTopGoalScorersByCompetitionAndSeason($competition, $season)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
       ->createQuery('SELECT g, COUNT(g) as scored
           FROM EliteFifaBundle:Goal g
           JOIN g.match m
           JOIN g.player p
           WHERE m.league = :competition
           AND m.season = :season
           GROUP BY g.player')
       ->setParameter('competition', $competition)
       ->setParameter('season', $season);

    return $query->getResult();
```

}

In view (controller has been omitted but assume it's there):

```
{% for scorer in goalScorers %}
    {{ scorer.player.name }} {{ scorer.scored }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

> Key "player" for array with keys "scored" does not exist in
>   EliteFifaBundle:League:show.html.twig at line 86

Comment: Do you get any error, or you just have issue on the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [symfony2 - Doctrine - How to do a multiple select with a count and group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992156/symfony2-doctrine-how-to-do-a-multiple-select-with-a-count-and-group-by)